# getting a Typescript annotation error in my redux reducer in vscode, even though I'm not writing anything in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types, annotations

in my reducer file, all declarations of this type,
`const newValue: action.payload.value;` all are red-underlined and VSCODE throws a compiler error that says:
"Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files."

However, I have not indicated or configured anything in my create-react-app project that should check for typescript syntax, at all.

This is breaking my app, not sure why.

```
import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  userName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  confirmPassword: ""
}

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_USER: {
      const newFirst: action.payload.firstName;
      const newLast: action.payload.lastName;
      const newUserName: action.payload.userName;
      const newEmail: action.payload.email;
      const newPass: action.payload.password;
      const newConfirmPass: action.payload.newPassword;
      return {
        ...state,
        firstName: newFirst,
        lastName: newLast,
        userName: newUserName,
        email: newEmail,
        password: newPass,
        confirmPassword: newConfirmPass
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
} 

export default userReducer;
```

VSCODE terminal error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/reducers/reducer.js
  Line 15:47:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  13 |   switch(action.type) {
  14 |     case types.UPDATE_USER: {
> 15 |       const newFirst: action.payload.firstName;
     |                                               ^
  16 |       const newLast: action.payload.lastName;
  17 |       const newUserName: action.payload.userName;
  18 |       const newEmail: action.payload.email;
```

broswer error:

```
index.js:1 ./src/reducers/reducer.js
  Line 15:47:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  13 |   switch(action.type) {
  14 |     case types.UPDATE_USER: {
> 15 |       const newFirst: action.payload.firstName;
     |                                               ^
  16 |       const newLast: action.payload.lastName;
  17 |       const newUserName: action.payload.userName;
  18 |       const newEmail: action.payload.email;
```

Comment: You're using a colon when you need an equals sign. `const newFirst: action.payload.firstName;` needs to be `const newFirst = action.payload.firstName;`, and similar for the other lines.

Comment: yes that was it thank you!